# Организация связи между таблицами (DBF) в Delphi

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы узнать, как организовать связь между таблицами используя компонент `DBGrid` для отображения из БД.

Например есть таблицы `"Товар"`, структура:

- [id] ключевое поле (автоинкремент, счетчик)
- [nazvanie] название товара
- [id_ed_izm] здесь ID из таблицы единицы измерения

И таблица '"Единицы измерения"`, структура:

- [id] ключевое поле (автоинкремент, счетчик)
- [nazvanie] название

И есть такая запись в таблице `"Товар"`:

```
|1|Ручка|1|
```

А также `"Единицы измерения"`:

```
|1|Шт.|
```

Ну и в тоге, если вывести из товара записи то получится (1 ручка 1), а хотелось бы видеть (1 ручка шт.), т.е. чтобы вместо 1 автоматически отображалось название из другой таблицы.

Пример простой, но поможет для более сложных задач.

Comment: А Join не устраивает?

Comment: Не знаю почему я тут не вижу комментария, но пришел по почте такой:
"А Join не устраивает?"

Хотелось бы без использования SQL, вроде можно устанавливать статические связи подобные (и даже возможно использовать в этом случае поля как подстановочные с раскрывающимся списком), но как именно не знаю. В книжках обычно испльзуются ADO, но мне бы с компонентами DataSource, Table, DBGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работа с полями, что для технологии ADO, что для BDE, практически одна и та же, поскольку поле - это самостоятельный класс (TField). Связать обе таблицы можно разными способами (для начала открыть редактор полей таблиц двойным щелчком по каждой таблице, вызвать контекстное меню правой мышкой и выбрать пункт Add all fields):

1. Указать в подчинённой таблице (TTable, TADOTable) по какому полю связывать (свойство MasterFields) и указать главную таблицу (свойство MasterSource);
2. Или в окне редактора кода перейти на закладку Diagram, туда переместить мышью нужные таблицы из объекта дерева (Object TreeView), затем подводим мышь с нажатой левой кнопкой к краю главной таблицы и, не отпуская, ведём до подчинённой таблицы, затем откроется окно, в котором выбираем поля главной таблицы (MasterFields) и поля подчинённой таблицы (DetailFields), жмём на Ok - таблицы связаны.

А для создания подстановочного поля нужно:

1. Убрать из таблицы поле id_ed_izm, установив свойство Visible = false;
2. Добавить в эту таблицу новое поле (вызвать контекстное меню в редакторе таблиц и выбрать пункт Add New Field) и указать: FieldType - lookup, Type - string, size - например, 5, Key fields - id_ed_izm, Lookup keys - id, Data Set - таблицу "Единицы измерения" , Result field - nazvanie.
   Если я ничего не напутал, то должно работать.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за все ваши ответы. и подробные и сокращеннные :) Очень помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в Delphi в вашем Table поле типа Lookup и сошлите его на таблицу "Единицы измерения".