# Организация связи между таблицами

Tags: delphi, interbase

Добрый день, товарищи!

Я вдохновился [этим постом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/36973/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-dbf-%D0%B2-delphi) и пытаюсь сделать тоже самое, только в динамическом порядке.
Сейчас опишу свои действия, потом скажу, что не получилось, а затем прошу сказать мне, где я ошибся.

1. В отдельном классе создаю компоненты для обработки запросов и вывода результатов:

   ```
   Query                 := TIBQuery.Create(MyOwner);  
   Query.AutoCalcFields  := True;  
   Query.Database        := DefDataBase;  

   Table                 := TIBTable.Create(MyOwner);  
   Table.AutoCalcFields  := True;  
   Table.Database        := DefDataBase;  
   Table.Transaction     := DefTransaction;  
   Table.IndexFieldNames := 'ID';  

   DataSource            := TDataSource.Create(MyOwner);  
   DataSource.AutoEdit   := True;  
   DataSource.DataSet    := Table;
   ```
2. Создаю объект этого класса и подключаю к нему DBGrid. Тут все нормально, данные в DBGrid отображаются корректно.
3. Пытаюсь программно добавить поле в объект Table:

   ```
   NewField:= TField.Create(Table);
   NewField.FieldName          := 'REF_MANAGER';
   NewField.Name               := 'REF_MANAGER';
   NewField.Visible            := true;

   NewField.KeyFields          := 'MANAGER';
   NewField.FieldKind          := fkLookUp;
   NewField.LookupDataSet      := TDataSet(IbComponents.RetrieveComponent(USERS)); // тут обычная функция, которая возвращает компонент TIbTable
   NewField.LookupKeyFields    := 'ID';
   NewField.LookupResultField  := 'SNAME';
   Table.Fields.Add(NewField);
   ```

Ошибок тут не возникает. Если вывожу в стринглист список полей в Table, то мое поле там есть. Но в DBGrid'е изменения не отображаются. В этом, собственно, вся загвоздка.

---

PS. я давно тут не был, куда подевалось форматирование кода?

Comment: Помню, у `TTable` есть свойство `AutoRefresh` (должно быть `true`), может в этом дело?
Форматирование кода - фигурные скобочки.

Comment: изменения не отображаются имеется в виду, что колонки в гриде нету или данные колонки не верные?  
в нумерованном списке код оформляется дополнительными 4 пробелами отступа.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, вот смотри:  
изначально у нас есть  
-
ID|Менеджер|Стоимость  
-
1 | 1......| 123456  
-
Потом добавляю дополнительный столбец REF_Менеджер в котором будет не ID, а имя менеджера. И все это должно было бы выглядеть так:  
-
ID|Менеджер|REF_Менеджер|Стоимость  
- 
1 | 1......| Егор.......| 123456   
- 
Но ничего не изменяется, и все равно все отображается, как в вариенте №1

Comment: это не TTable, а TIBTable. И у этой таблицы нет такого свойства

Comment: дак в грид такие колонки тоже вручную надо добавлять. afair добавляется автоматом только то, что в fieldDefs датасета. Но проще колонки добавлять вручную, там и ширину колонки и заголовок подправить проще...

Comment: ну у меня колонки автоматом считываются, а потом подгружаются конфиги для каждой таблицы, и по этим конфигам настраиваются лэйблы и ширина колонок.  
Сейчас тогда сделаю еще и добавление новых колонок, просто я думал, что они в гриде автоматом будут появляться...